# How can I upgrade wordpress with manual?

Tags: updates, upgrade

When I update or upgrade my site automatically ,it corrupted. How can I update or upgrade it safely and manually?

Comment: Explain what _corrupted_ means. Be specific to get useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "Manual" install involves [downloading the WordPress zip](http://wordpress.org/download/) and extracting it to your site directory (via ftp or a file manager like cPanel has). make sure your `wp-content` folder is fully backed up as you will need it. then run the extract.